# The pattern space and hold space of the Sed utility has an initialized value of null or empty string?

Tags: sed

From the documentation of sed:

> sed maintains two data buffers: the active pattern space, and the
>   auxiliary hold space. Both are initially empty.

I initially think the value of pattern space and hold space is null (nothing). But from the following example, it seems that the initially value of them is a single newline character (\n).

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat e.txt 
aa
bb
cc
dd
[root@localhost ~]# cat e.txt | sed -r '/c/{x;p;x}'
aa
bb

cc
dd
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Is my understanding right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is that the `p` command, like the default print action, is actually adding a newline to the end of the empty pattern space. This is based on [this little snippet](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Execution-Cycle) from the GNU `sed` documentation (just below that bit you quote, by the way):

> `sed` operates by performing the following cycle on each line of input: first, `sed` reads one line from the input stream, removes any trailing newline, and places it in the pattern space.
>
> ... blah, blah blah ...
>
> When the end of the script is reached, unless the `-n` option is in use, the contents of pattern space are printed out to the output stream, adding back the trailing newline if it was removed.

In other words, the line being held in the pattern (and hold) space does not have the trailing newline - the `aa` line is held as `aa` rather than `aa<newline>`.

Of course, the hold space may still contain multiple lines but that just means that executing the `H` command on the first two lines of your file will give you a hold space containing `aa<newline>bb`, not `aa<newline>bb<newline>`.

Comment: A very useful, if little known, in GNU sed is the `l` command. Especially good for working out what is going on in HS an PS when they contain multi-lines.